# Gnome Terminal Icon Licence, .xcf

Tags: icons, gimp, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using humanity system icons for created application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35578/using-humanity-system-icons-for-created-application)

I would like to use gnome terminal icon (/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/128/utilities-terminal.svg) as a starting point to create new icon for my Ubuntu app.

- Is this a copyright issue?
- Can I find .xcf source file for this icon?

Comment: Can't answer your second question, as Oli was faster closing it. An .svg icon is a vector graphic, .xcf is a bitmap graphic format. It's most likely that the source file is the .svg, and that the icon was created in a vector graphics editing program like Inkscape, not with the Gimp.

Comment: Sources are SVG (vectors) that can be opened and edited in Applications like Inkscape, Adobe Illustrator (Windows/Mac), etc. It's just a markup language so you could even edit it with a text editor. I believe the SVGs are distributed but if they're not, you can get them [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementarydesign/humanity/Humanity/files/head:/Humanity/) along with the `COPYING` license file.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, they are distributed. I installed Inkscape. Now newbie will try to do some vector graphics :)